# How to get the parent DOM element reference of an angular2 component

Tags: angular, dom, angular2-components

I need to access to some properties of the parent DOM element which contains the component from where i want to get the info, is there a way to do such thing?

Here is how my component looks like:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

import "./loadingSpinner.component.css!";

    @Component({
        selector: "loading-spinner",
        template: `
            <div *ngIf="showSpinner" class="loader-directive-wrapper">
                <div class="loader"></div>
            </div>`
    })
    export class LoadingSpinnerComponent {
        @Input() public showSpinner: boolean = false;
    }
```

Comment: I need to have access to the parent DOM element, not the parent component, i need to know some parent DOM properties like width or height

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```ts
constructor(elementRef:ElementRef) {
  elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement....
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit? Preferably with an example ? Why are there trailing dots in the last ? Which object/variable is the child able to use now ? Is this to be added in child or parent component?

Comment: The parent dots are your custom code 
This code is the child element. `elementRef` points to "self" and "elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement" points to the parent element.
If you want to access the component instead of the element then you need to inject the component. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree#find-a-parent-component-of-known-type

Answer (score 4):

In your child component pass parent in constructor:

```
  constructor(
    private parent: ParentComponent,
    ...
  )

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.parent);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Tukkan, but i need to access the parent DOM element not the component, i guess i formulated the question wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The child component shouldn't update properties on the parent. Instead have the child emit events and the parent change the properties. The docs have an example in the [Component Interaction section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent).

Answer (score 0):

for accessing values of parent you can use @input. for changing parent values 
try this example

child component

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rio-counter',
  templateUrl: 'app/counter.component.html'
})
export class CounterComponent {
  @Input()  count = 0;
  @Output() result = new EventEmitter<number>();

  increment() {
    this.count++;
    this.result.emit(this.count);
  }
}
```

child html part

```
<div>
  <p>Count: {{ count }}</p>
  <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
</div>
```

parent component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rio-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  num = 0;
  parentCount = 0;

  assignparentcount(val: number) {
    this.parentCount = val;
  }
}
```

parent html part

```
<div>
  Parent Num: {{ num }}<br>
  Parent Count: {{ parentCount }}
  <rio-counter [count]="num" (result)="assignparentcount($event)">
  </rio-counter>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from the parent component, you may want to review data exchange methods between components.  It seems to me that you may want to take a look at the Input decorator.
You can do something like:
`<app-spinner show="true"></app-spinner>`
Or
`<app-spinner show="isBusy()"></app-spinner>`

Take a look at it here: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: I think that what the question is asking is the exact opposite, something that uses ```@Output``` and listens for it in the parent.