# How to set Angular2 component input conditionally?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Consider the following case.

Parent component:

```
<div title="title1">
  <my-component input="title2"></my-component>
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

MyComponent:

```
<div [title]="input">ABC</div>
```

The problem here is that first "ABC" div will have the `"title2"` tooltip while the second one will have whatever MyComponent has as default value for `input`, and this will "override" `"title1"` tooltip which is not desired.

How can I avoid setting "title" in MyComponent template if no "input" is received?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273384/how-to-get-the-parent-dom-element-reference-of-an-angular2-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that binding the `title` property of the child element will override the parent `title`, even when `input` is `null` or `undefined`. However, according to [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bo4lc6), binding the title attribute with `[attr.title]` allows to inherit the parent `title` when `input` is `null` or `undefined`:

```
<div [attr.title]="input">ABC</div>
```

with

```
@Input() input: string; // undefined by default
```