# How to Access an Ancestor-Components ElementRef inside a Component/Directive

Tags: angular, angular-ivy, angular-injector

I want to access the `ElementRef` of an ancestor component
*(which is not controlled by me; means I cannot simply expose the desired object on it)*.

So basically I could inject the Component itself and then use the functionality of the `render3#getHostElement` function (returns the ElementRef of a given Component Instance but unfortunately it is not exported from the `@angular/core` package).

```html
<mat-form-field>                  <!-- the elRef of this one; but is potentially not a direct ancestor -->
  <div>                           <!-- potentially some other elements in between -->
    <my-component></my-component>
  </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(formField: MatFormField) {
   const elRefOfFormField = getHostElement(formField) // basically what I need
  }
}
```

So is there a 'clean' way to receive this HostElement?

- imho it should be sth analogous to how I can access a children ElementRef of a component `@ViewChild(MatFormField, {read: ElementRef})`

It's not an option to do something like `elementRef.nativeElement.closest('mat-form-field')` (sometimes there are multiple options how to use a component/directive).

Comment: you can use a service, set the value there and then you can use it across the angular application. Just make sure the service is injected in the AppModule

Comment: @Manish it would then be better to just provide it through an `@Input()`. But the goal is to have the solution self-contained and generic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the parent DOM element reference of an angular2 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273384/how-to-get-the-parent-dom-element-reference-of-an-angular2-component)

Comment: @jhyot - the other component is potentially not a direct parent in the DOM - therefore no.